# Flutter app only receiving FCM messages to specific token

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am updating my Flutter app in order to receive Firebase Cloud Messaging messages.

I have followed all needed changes in the app and on Firebase console.

Now I am trying to send a test message from FCM to my android device, but it only receives a message when sent using the test message option with an specific token.

It doesn't receive a normal message to all devices.

This is the main.dart code I am using:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  _firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("onMessage: $message");
    },
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("onLaunch: $message");
    },
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("onResume: $message");
    },
  );
  _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
      const IosNotificationSettings(
          sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: false));
  _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
      .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
    print("Settings registered: $settings");
  });
  _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
    assert(token != null);

    print("token firebase " + token);
  });

  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: gettoken save in firebase db or firestore everytime when user logs in. Monitor when messaging happens on your database. When it happens, gather the destination user, get the token(s) associated to this user and send one FCM

Comment: @MajidAli, but I should be able to send one FCM to the app also when the user is not logged in if I send a FCM from the FCM console to the app I want, isn't true?

Comment: every device has their own unique token If the same user is logged in to two devices If so, you'll need to store multiple device tokens per user. just for the info

Comment: yes you can its true but you will be able to send FCM to a specific device..

Comment: @MajidAli, I would like to get the two options, to send FCM to all devices and to send FCM to specific device.

Comment: you cant send FCM on multiple devices with same token..

Comment: 1 device = 1 token

Comment: @MajidAli, I guess you don't understand what I need or I am not clear enough in my poor english. I know that every device receives an unique token from FCM. But I need to send a FCM to all devices that have the app installed, not only to one specific device. I assume that using the FCM console, if I select the app as target of the FCM, the message should be sent to all devices, and this is not happening. I can only send a FCM if I put the token of every device

Comment: Yes you can only send fcm if you put token of every device..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that all devices are subscribed to topic.